# Implementation of the bidirectional graph search

Tags: java, search, graph, artificial-intelligence, bidirectional-search

I am trying to implement a [bi-directional graph search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search). As I understand, I should somehow merge two breadth-first searches, one which starts at the starting (or root) node and one which starts at the goal (or end) node. The bi-directional search terminates when both breadth-first searches "meet" at the same vertex.

Could you provide me with a code example (in Java, if possible) or link with code for the bidirectional graph search?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming you have `Node`s like this (in the file `Node.java`):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Node<T> {
    private final T data; // The data that you want to store in this node.
    private final Set<Node> adjacentNodes = new HashSet<>();

    // Constructor
    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // Getters

    /*
     * Returns the data stored in this node.
     * */
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /*
     * Returns a set of the adjacent nodes of this node.
     * */
    public Set<Node> getAdjacentNodes() {
        return adjacentNodes;
    }

    // Setters

    /*
     * Attempts to add node to the set of adjacent nodes of this node. If it was not previously added, it is added, and
     * true is returned. If it was previously added, it returns false.
     * */
    public boolean addAdjacent(Node node) {
        return adjacentNodes.add(node);
    }
}
```

Then the bidirectional search algorithm (defined in the file `BidirectionalSearch.java`) would look something like this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class BidirectionalSearch {

    /*
     * Returns true if a path exists between Node a and b, false otherwise.
     * */
    public static boolean pathExists(Node a, Node b) {
        // LinkedList implements the Queue interface, FIFO queue operations (e.g., add and poll).

        // Queue to hold the paths from Node a.
        Queue<Node> queueA = new LinkedList<>();

        // Queue to hold the paths from Node a.
        Queue<Node> queueB = new LinkedList<>();

        // A set of visited nodes starting from Node a.
        Set<Node> visitedA = new HashSet<>();

        // A set of visited nodes starting from Node b.
        Set<Node> visitedB = new HashSet<>();

        visitedA.add(a);
        visitedB.add(b);

        queueA.add(a);
        queueB.add(b);

        // Both queues need to be empty to exit the while loop.
        while (!queueA.isEmpty() || !queueB.isEmpty()) {
            if (pathExistsHelper(queueA, visitedA, visitedB)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (pathExistsHelper(queueB, visitedB, visitedA)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static boolean pathExistsHelper(Queue<Node> queue,
                                            Set<Node> visitedFromThisSide,
                                            Set<Node> visitedFromThatSide) {
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node next = queue.remove();

            Set<Node> adjacentNodes = next.getAdjacentNodes();

            for (Node adjacent : adjacentNodes) {

                // If the visited nodes, starting from the other direction,
                // contain the "adjacent" node of "next", then we can terminate the search
                if (visitedFromThatSide.contains(adjacent)) {
                    return true;
                } else if (visitedFromThisSide.add(adjacent)) {
                    queue.add(adjacent);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test here the implementation above.
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this algorithm scan the entire graph via queueA? In `pathExistsHelper`, every adjacent node is immediately added back to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Logic:
In normal course, BFS is recursive. But here we cannot have it recursive because if we start with recursion, then it will cover all nodes from one side (start or end) and will only stop if it is not able to find the end or finds the end.

So in order to do a bidirectional search, the logic will be explained with the example below:

```
/*
Let's say this is the graph
        2------5------8
       /              |
      /               |
     /                |
    1---3------6------9
     \                |
      \               |
       \              |
        4------7------10
We want to find the path between nodes 1 and 9. In order to do this we will need 2 DS, one for recording the path form beginning and other from end:*/

ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>>> startTrav = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>>> endTrav = new ArrayList<>();

/*Before starting the loop, initialise these with the values shown below:
startTrav --> index=0 --> <1, {1}>
endTrav --> index=0 --> <9, {9}>

Note here that in the HashMap, the key is the node that we have reached and the value is a linkedList containing the path used to reach to that node. 
Now inside the loop we will start traversal on startTrav 1st. We will traverse it from index 0 to 0, and while traversing what ever children are there for the node under process, we will add in startTrav. So startTrav will transform like:
startTrav --> index=0 --> <1, {1}>
startTrav --> index=1 --> <2, {1,2}>
startTrav --> index=2 --> <3, {1,3}>
startTrav --> index=3 --> <4, {1,4}>

Now we will check for collision, i.e if either of nodes that we have covered in startTrav are found in endTrav (i.e if either of 1,2,3,4 is present in endTrav's list = 9). The answer is no, so continue loop.

Now do the same from endTrav
endTrav --> index=0 --> <9, {9}>
endTrav --> index=1 --> <8, {9,8}>
endTrav --> index=2 --> <6, {9,6}>
endTrav --> index=3 --> <10, {9,10}>

Now again we will check for collision, i.e if either of nodes that we have covered in startTrav are found in endTrav (i.e if either of 1,2,3,4 is present in endTrav's list = 9,8,6,10). The answer is no so continue loop.
// end of 1st iteration of while loop

// beginning of 2nd iteration of while loop
startTrav --> index=0 --> <1, {1}>
startTrav --> index=1 --> <2, {1,2}>
startTrav --> index=2 --> <3, {1,3}>
startTrav --> index=3 --> <4, {1,4}>
startTrav --> index=4 --> <5, {1,2,5}>
startTrav --> index=5 --> <6, {1,3,6}>
startTrav --> index=6 --> <7, {1,4,7}>

Now again we will check for collision, i.e if either of nodes that we have covered in startTrav are found in endTrav (i.e if either of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 is present in endTrav's list = 9,8,6,10). The answer is yes. Colission has occurred on node 6. Break the loop now.

Now pick the path to 6 from startTrav and pick the path to 6 from endTrav and merge the 2.*/
```

Code for this is as below:

```
class Node<T> {
    public T value;
    public LinkedList<Node<T>> nextNodes = new LinkedList<>();
}
class Graph<T>{
    public HashMap<Integer, Node<T>> graph=new HashMap<>();
}
public class BiDirectionalBFS {
    public LinkedList<Node<Integer>> findPath(Graph<Integer> graph, int startNode, int endNode) {
        if(!graph.graph.containsKey(startNode) || !graph.graph.containsKey(endNode)) return null;

        if(startNode==endNode) {
            LinkedList<Node<Integer>> ll = new LinkedList<>();
            ll.add(graph.graph.get(startNode));
            return ll;
        }
        ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>>> startTrav = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>>> endTrav = new ArrayList<>();

        boolean[] traversedNodesFromStart = new boolean[graph.graph.size()];
        boolean[] traversedNodesFromEnd = new boolean[graph.graph.size()];

        addDetailsToAL(graph, startNode, startTrav, traversedNodesFromStart, null);
        addDetailsToAL(graph, endNode, endTrav, traversedNodesFromEnd, null);

        int collision = -1, startIndex=0, endIndex=0;

        while (startTrav.size()>startIndex && endTrav.size()>endIndex) {

            // Cover all nodes in AL from start and add new
            int temp=startTrav.size();
            for(int i=startIndex; i<temp; i++) {
                recordAllChild(graph, startTrav, i, traversedNodesFromStart);
            }
            startIndex=temp;

            //check collision
            if((collision = checkColission(traversedNodesFromStart, traversedNodesFromEnd))!=-1) {
                break;
            }

            //Cover all nodes in AL from end and add new
            temp=endTrav.size();
            for(int i=endIndex; i<temp; i++) {
                recordAllChild(graph, endTrav, i, traversedNodesFromEnd);
            }
            endIndex=temp;

            //check collision
            if((collision = checkColission(traversedNodesFromStart, traversedNodesFromEnd))!=-1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        LinkedList<Node<Integer>> pathFromStart = null, pathFromEnd = null;
        if(collision!=-1) {
            for(int i =0;i<traversedNodesFromStart.length && (pathFromStart==null || pathFromEnd==null); i++) {
                if(pathFromStart==null && startTrav.get(i).keySet().iterator().next()==collision) {
                    pathFromStart=startTrav.get(i).get(collision);
                }
                if(pathFromEnd==null && endTrav.get(i).keySet().iterator().next()==collision) {
                    pathFromEnd=endTrav.get(i).get(collision);
                }
            }
            pathFromEnd.removeLast();
            ListIterator<Node<Integer>> li = pathFromEnd.listIterator();
            while(li.hasNext()) li.next();
            while(li.hasPrevious()) {
                pathFromStart.add(li.previous());
            }
            return pathFromStart;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void recordAllChild(Graph<Integer> graph, ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>>> listToAdd, int index, boolean[] traversedNodes) {
        HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>> record=listToAdd.get(index);
        Integer recordKey = record.keySet().iterator().next();
        for(Node<Integer> child:graph.graph.get(recordKey).nextNodes) {
            if(traversedNodes[child.value]!=true) {                 addDetailsToAL(graph, child.getValue(), listToAdd, traversedNodes, record.get(recordKey));
            }
        }
    }
    private void addDetailsToAL(Graph<Integer> graph, Integer node, ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>>> startTrav,
            boolean[] traversalArray, LinkedList<Node<Integer>> oldLLContent) {
        LinkedList<Node<Integer>> ll = oldLLContent==null?new LinkedList<>() : new LinkedList<>(oldLLContent);
        ll.add(graph.graph.get(node));
        HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put(node, ll);
        startTrav.add(hm);
        traversalArray[node]=true;
    }

    private int checkColission(boolean[] start, boolean[] end) {
        for (int i=0; i<start.length; i++) {
            if(start[i] && end[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

A much more neater and easier to understand approach can be though Arrays. We will replace the complex DS :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>>>
```

with a simple

```
LinkedList<Node<Integer>>[]
```

Here, the index of the LL will define the numeric value of the node. So if the node has value 7, then the path to reach 7 will be stored at index 7 in the array. Also we will remove the boolean arrays for finding which path to which element is found as that can be achieved with our linkedList array itself. We will add 2

```
LinkedList<Node<Integer>>
```

which will be used for storing the children as in case of level order traversal of tree. Lastly, we for storing the path for traversal from end, we will store it in reverse order, so that while merging, we do not need to reverse the elements from the 2nd array. Code for this goes as below:

```
class Node<T> {
    public T value;
    public LinkedList<Node<T>> nextNodes = new LinkedList<>();
}
class Graph<T>{
    public HashMap<Integer, Node<T>> graph=new HashMap<>();
}
public class BiDirectionalBFS {
    private LinkedList<Node<Integer>> findPathUsingArrays(Graph<Integer> graph, int startNode, int endNode) {
        if(!graph.graph.containsKey(startNode) || !graph.graph.containsKey(endNode)) return null;

        if(startNode==endNode) {
            LinkedList<Node<Integer>> ll = new LinkedList<>();
            ll.add(graph.graph.get(startNode));
            return ll;
        }
        LinkedList<Node<Integer>>[] startTrav = new LinkedList[graph.graph.size()];
        LinkedList<Node<Integer>>[] endTrav = new LinkedList[graph.graph.size()];

        LinkedList<Node<Integer>> traversedNodesFromStart = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Node<Integer>> traversedNodesFromEnd = new LinkedList<>();

        addToDS(graph, traversedNodesFromStart, startTrav, startNode);
        addToDS(graph, traversedNodesFromEnd, endTrav, endNode);

        int collision = -1;

        while (traversedNodesFromStart.size()>0 && traversedNodesFromEnd.size()>0) {

            // Cover all nodes in LL from start and add new
            recordAllChild(traversedNodesFromStart.size(), traversedNodesFromStart, startTrav, true);

            //check collision
            if((collision = checkColission(startTrav, endTrav))!=-1) {
                break;
            }

            //Cover all nodes in LL from end and add new
            recordAllChild(traversedNodesFromEnd.size(), traversedNodesFromEnd, endTrav, false);

            //check collision
            if((collision = checkColission(startTrav, endTrav))!=-1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(collision!=-1) {
            endTrav[collision].removeFirst();
            startTrav[collision].addAll(endTrav[collision]);
            return startTrav[collision];
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void recordAllChild(int temp, LinkedList<Node<Integer>> traversedNodes, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>[] travArr, boolean addAtLast) {
        while (temp>0) {
            Node<Integer> node = traversedNodes.remove();
            for(Node<Integer> child : node.nextNodes) {
                if(travArr[child.value]==null) {
                    traversedNodes.add(child);
                    LinkedList<Node<Integer>> ll=new LinkedList<>(travArr[node.value]);
                    if(addAtLast) {
                        ll.add(child);
                    } else {
                        ll.addFirst(child);
                    }
                    travArr[child.value]=ll;
                    traversedNodes.add(child);
                }
            }
            temp--;
        }
    }

    private int checkColission(LinkedList<Node<Integer>>[] startTrav, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>[] endTrav) {
        for (int i=0; i<startTrav.length; i++) {
            if(startTrav[i]!=null && endTrav[i]!=null) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void addToDS(Graph<Integer> graph, LinkedList<Node<Integer>> traversedNodes, LinkedList<Node<Integer>>[] travArr, int node) {
        LinkedList<Node<Integer>> ll = new LinkedList<>();
        ll.add(graph.graph.get(node));
        travArr[node]=ll;
        traversedNodes.add(graph.graph.get(node));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Graph.java

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Graph<T> {
    private T value;
    private Set<Graph> adjacents = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<String> visitors = new HashSet<>();

    public Graph(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void addAdjacent(Graph adjacent) {
        this.adjacents.add(adjacent);
    }

    public Set<Graph> getAdjacents() {
        return this.adjacents;
    }

    public void setVisitor(String visitor) {
        this.visitors.add(visitor);
    }

    public boolean hasVisitor(String visitor) {
        return this.visitors.contains(visitor);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("Value [").append(value).append("] visitors[");
        if (!visitors.isEmpty()) {
            for (String visitor : visitors) {
                sb.append(visitor).append(",");
            }
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString().replace(",]", "]");
    }
}
```

GraphHelper.java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

public class GraphHelper {
    // implements singleton pattern
    private static GraphHelper instance;

    private GraphHelper() {
    }

    /**
     * @return the instance
     */
    public static GraphHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new GraphHelper();
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isRoute(Graph gr1, Graph gr2) {
        Queue<Graph> queue1 = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Graph> queue2 = new LinkedList<>();

        addToQueue(queue1, gr1, "1");
        addToQueue(queue2, gr2, "2");

        while (!queue1.isEmpty() || !queue2.isEmpty()) {
            if (!queue1.isEmpty()) {
                Graph gAux1 = queue1.remove();
                Iterator<Graph> it1 = gAux1.getAdjacents().iterator();

                while (it1.hasNext()) {
                    Graph adj1 = it1.next();
                    System.out.println("adj1 " + adj1);
                    if (adj1.hasVisitor("2"))
                        return true;
                    else if (!adj1.hasVisitor("1"))
                        addToQueue(queue1, adj1, "1");
                }
            }

            if (!queue2.isEmpty()) {
                Graph gAux2 = queue2.remove();
                Iterator<Graph> it2 = gAux2.getAdjacents().iterator();
                while (it2.hasNext()) {
                    Graph adj2 = it2.next();
                    System.out.println("adj2 " + adj2);
                    if (adj2.hasVisitor("1"))
                        return true;
                    else if (!adj2.hasVisitor("2"))
                        addToQueue(queue2, adj2, "2");
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void addToQueue(Queue<Graph> queue, Graph gr, String visitor) {
        gr.setVisitor(visitor);
        queue.add(gr);
    }
}
```

GraphTest.java

```
public class GraphTest {
    private GraphHelper helper = GraphHelper.getInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphTest test = new GraphTest();
        test.testIsRoute();
    }

    public void testIsRoute() {
        Graph commonGraph = new Graph<String>("z");
        System.out
                .println("Expected true, result [" + helper.isRoute(graph1(commonGraph), graph2(commonGraph)) + "]\n");

        commonGraph = new Graph<String>("z");
        System.out.println("Expected false, result [" + helper.isRoute(graph1(commonGraph), graph2(null)) + "]\n");
    }

    private Graph graph1(Graph commonGraph) {
        Graph main = new Graph<String>("a");
        Graph graphb = new Graph<String>("b");
        Graph graphc = new Graph<String>("c");
        Graph graphd = new Graph<String>("d");
        Graph graphe = new Graph<String>("e");

        graphb.addAdjacent(graphc);
        graphb.addAdjacent(graphe);
        if (commonGraph != null)
            graphb.addAdjacent(commonGraph);

        graphd.addAdjacent(graphc);
        graphd.addAdjacent(graphe);
        graphd.addAdjacent(main);

        main.addAdjacent(graphb);
        main.addAdjacent(graphd);

        return main;
    }

    private Graph graph2(Graph commonGraph) {
        Graph main = new Graph<String>("f");
        Graph graphg = new Graph<String>("g");
        Graph graphh = new Graph<String>("h");
        Graph graphi = new Graph<String>("i");
        Graph graphj = new Graph<String>("j");

        graphg.addAdjacent(graphh);
        graphg.addAdjacent(graphj);
        if (commonGraph != null)
            graphg.addAdjacent(commonGraph);

        graphi.addAdjacent(graphh);
        graphi.addAdjacent(graphj);
        graphi.addAdjacent(main);

        main.addAdjacent(graphg);
        main.addAdjacent(graphi);

        return main;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a GraphNode as the following structure (using standard arrays) and supposing that you can modify the GraphNode structure by adding two flags used to track the visited nodes (to avoid loops):

```
public class GraphNode {

  public Integer value;
  public GraphNode[] nodes;

  public boolean markedsource = false;
  public boolean markedtarget = false;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      GraphNode graphNode = (GraphNode) o;
      return Objects.equals(value, graphNode.value);
  }

}
```

This is the solution:

**boolean found = bidirectionalSearch(source, target);**

```
// ..... 

private static boolean bidirectionalSearch(GraphNode sourceNode, GraphNode targetNode) {
    HashSet<GraphNode> sourceSet = new HashSet<>();
    sourceSet.add(sourceNode);

    HashSet<GraphNode> targetSet = new HashSet<>();
    targetSet.add(targetNode);

    return bidirectionalSearch(sourceSet, targetSet, sourceNode, targetNode);
}

private static boolean bidirectionalSearch(Set<GraphNode> sourceSet, Set<GraphNode> targetSet, GraphNode sourceNode, GraphNode targetNode) {

    Set<GraphNode> intersection = sourceSet.stream().filter(targetSet::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if (!intersection.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("intersection found at: " + intersection.iterator().next().value);
        return true;
    } else if (sourceSet.contains(targetNode) || targetSet.contains(sourceNode)) {
        return true;
    } else if (sourceSet.isEmpty() && targetSet.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    sourceSet = sourceSet.stream().flatMap(BidirectionalSearch::getGraphNodeStreamSource)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    targetSet = targetSet.stream().flatMap(
            BidirectionalSearch::getGraphNodeStreamTarget).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return bidirectionalSearch(sourceSet, targetSet, sourceNode, targetNode);
}

private static Stream<GraphNode> getGraphNodeStreamSource(GraphNode n) {
    if (n.nodes != null)
        return Arrays.stream(n.nodes).filter(b -> {
            if (!b.markedsource) {
                b.markedsource = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

private static Stream<GraphNode> getGraphNodeStreamTarget(GraphNode n) {
    if (n.nodes != null)
        return Arrays.stream(n.nodes).filter(b -> {
            if (!b.markedtarget) {
                b.markedtarget = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works by expanding the *sourceSet* and the *targetSet* for each iteration, by considering adjacent nodes of the sets in input.

[image: Example iteration]

Now let's see advantages against a standard BFS (BreadthFirstSearch). If **K** is the biggest number of each node and the shortest path from the source to the target node is **D**, it's possible to shorten time complexity from O(k^D) to 2*O(K^(D/2)).

We have to consider also the added space of the two SETs and the time to check the intersection for every iteration.

With a standard BFS, you need a QUEUE that will have in the worst case all k^d elements of the node at the iteration K. In this case we will have two sets of k^d/2.